# Google play game services and SHA1 certificate

Tags: java, android, google-play

In google play game services, you have to link your apps to your Game service campaign. Whenever you link an app you have to authorize it by providing the package and then the SHA1 Signing certificate fingerprint. My question is if you generate the app's apk on a different computer, the SHA1 certificate will be different. So do you have to delete the linked app and re-add it with the new SHA1? The documentation is pretty unclear about this.

Comment: duplicate of [Android what is SHA1 fingerprint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061708/android-what-is-sha1-fingerprint)

Answer (score 0):

> My question is if you generate the app's apk on a different computer,
>   the SHA1 certificate will be different

Why would the certificate be different? You must use the same keystore and provide the keystore password every time you generate the APK for a release. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) about this.

> Warning: Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key.

Comment: I had assumed that you had to use the same keystore, but the key was freshly encrypted each time you generated a new apk with whatever SHA1 fingerprint was on your computer.

Comment: Have you seen the [troubleshoot section](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting)? You get the SHA1 of the certificate used to sign your apk.

Comment: Yeah I get that, but my question is, do you then have to update it on google play game services. Wen you authorize an app in game services you then have to provide the SHA1 in the developer console.