# SHA-1 Code Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, sha

I have one question. I writing Android app in Xamarin. I published it on Google Play.

As I understand when I reinstall Windows and Xamarin SHA-1 code will change. And I cannot publish my app updates?

Or how I can publish app without creating new in Google Play?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32085642/4984832

Comment: I need to save certificate file? @SushiHangover

Comment: Yes...https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html >A keystore is a binary file that contains a set of private keys. You must keep your keystore in a safe and secure place..... **Warning**: Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key.

Comment: Thank you so much. Post this to answer and I will mark it as right answer. @SushiHangover